# Can Firefox generate a different password for the same domain?

Tags: firefox, passwords

I’ve been going through my accounts having Firefox generate passwords for them instead of using the same set of passwords everywhere.  This was going great until I got to my multiple Google accounts, where Firefox wants to use the same autogenerated password I just set the first account to for my other accounts.

The “Use a Securely Generated Password” option is showing the password I already used for my first Google account, and if I right-click and choose “Use Generated Password...” nothing changes.  There is no username field visible on the form; just new password and confirm new password.

Is there a way to get Firefox to generate a second password for the same domain?  Seems like this would also be needed if one were to try to change their passwords every so often since Firefox would just “generate” the same password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried closing and reopening Firefox after setting the password for the first account and then it generated a new password.